# Where is this parameter passed to this callback function in Flutter documentation?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

Where/How is the parameter for `myTapCallback()` passed to The `MyListItem(myTapCallback)` call ?

```
    @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SomeWidget(
    // Construct the widget, passing it a reference to the method above.
    MyListItem(myTapCallback),  //<—- where is item?
  );
}

void myTapCallback(Item item) {
  print('user tapped on $item');
}
```

*Source: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyListItem` is a function which takes a `Function(Item item)` as a parameter. You're not passing the parameter item for `MyListItem`, the item will be provided internally by `MyListItem`. The only thing it needs as a parameter is a **function that takes an Item item** as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

From the code and the tutorial it looks like the code is constructing a MyListItem and passing a callback into the constructor. The MyListItem is probably going to use the callback internally when it is tapped and pass the Item into the callback